# How can i get the width/height of an image before appending that to the DOM/browser?

Tags: jquery, image, height, width, append

i would like to output the width and height of an image **before appending that to the browser**.
Of course, i get 0 for the width and 0 for the height, cause the image is not appended to the DOM yet.

I have **uploaded** my code to http://jsfiddle.net/BF5En/4/

How can i take the right values before appending the image to the DOM??

Thanks, in advance!

Answer (score 3):

You seem to have very interesting questions. This is my humble answer:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".Photos a").click(function () {
        var href_attribute = $(this).attr('href');
        var new_item = $('<img src="' + href_attribute + '" />')
            .hide()
            .load(function () {
                alert('Img was loaded! Width: ' + this.width + ' and height: ' + this.height);
            })
            .fadeIn(2000)
            .appendTo('.AppendingDiv');
        return false;
    });
});
```

**Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/hobobne/BF5En/10/**

You see, you must make sure that the image is preloaded, for that we use `.load()`. Otherwise you will get **0**. That's actually good, because it means that the script works, just everything is so fast, that it can get the dimensions. `.load()` makes sure that the image is first loaded and only then receive the dimensions.

For whatever purposes you wanted to use the dimensions, I recommend doing that inside the `.load()` as well. Because you probably will have multiple `.Photos a` anyways.

Also, as you might have noticed your `.fadeIn(2000)` was not working. That's because, your item got appended before you called it. As you can see, I fixed it for you :)

**NB!** Sorry, I renamed some of the variables (made stuff more logic in my head.)

Answer (score 0):

```
var MyitemWidth = item.css('width');
var MyitemHeight = item.css('height');
```

see this answer [Getting auto size of IMG before adding it to DOM (Using JQuery)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5438715/getting-auto-size-of-img-before-adding-it-to-dom-using-jquery/5438742#5438742)

```
DOM elements have dimensions only when added to a parent, as dimension is determined by the 
rendering engine. To go around this issue, have a <div> container absolutely positioned off 
screen, add the image to it first, get the dimension, then add the image at it's final destination.
```

Comment: Thanks for the anwser but i still get zeros for both height and width because the image is not appended to the browser yet

Comment: Thanks for the link, as i understood they propose using a "container absolutely positioned off screen". Is that the only solution or the best solution for the problem??I'm a bit confused with that...If i use the .load() function,am i going to have the desirable result??Is my layout going to be ruined with that absolute positioned element??

Comment: this may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1782566/determine-whether-element-has-fixed-or-percentage-width-using-javascript/1783565#1783565