# determine width and height of an image while it isn't inserted to the dom

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm receiving images inside a long string from a server using an ajax call

The url of the image is inside result[1] for sure.
I've used width/naturalWidth and height/naturalHeight and on occasion they return 0 and in other cases they return the right size in pixels

```
var imgElement = jQuery("<img>").attr("src", result[1]);
var width = imgElement[0].naturalWidth;
var height = imgElement[0].naturalHeight;
if (width >= that.minImgPixels && height >= that.minImgPixels) {
    image = result[1];
}
```

How is the right way to check image width and height without inserting it to the dom?

Comment: This answer to a similar question shows you how to progamatically create the image in javascript without it having to be in the dom first: http://stackoverflow.com/a/626505/1805956

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
function GetAnImage(src) {

    var newImg = document.createElement('img');
    newImg.src = src;

    return newImg;
}

var newImg = GetAnImage("abc.jpg");
newImg.onload = function () {                           
    var height = this.height;
    var width = this.width;  
    //do with the image as you want         
}
```

or see this link: [Getting auto size of IMG before adding it to DOM (Using JQuery)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5438715/getting-auto-size-of-img-before-adding-it-to-dom-using-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

The problem occures since settings the src of an `jQuery("<img>")`takes time and while it does that, the javascript continues to run to the next lines which produce 0 since the image wasn't loaded yet.

The solution is to set a load event like that:

```
var imgElement = jQuery("<img>").load(function(){
    var width = imgElement[0].naturalWidth;
    var height = imgElement[0].naturalHeight;
    if (width >= that.minImgPixels && height >= that.minImgPixels) {
        image = result[1];
    }
}).attr("src", result[1]);
```

Comment: see load method caveats at [http://api.jquery.com/load-event/](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/)