# jQuery make variable out of element before appending to DOM

Tags: jquery, string, variables, append, store

Trying to get efficient here. How can I store an element as a variable before appending it to the DOM? Seems like it's a waste to create it, append it, then go find it again to make a variable.

My method is below. OBV it's saving the string as a variable, not the object, but you get the idea.

Any magic for me or do I have to make two trips?

```
var $rGallery = '<section id="rGallery" />';

$bin.before($rGallery);

console.log($rGallery);
```

Comment: Some of these examples may or may not be useful to you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12009839/84206

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[`.before()`](http://api.jquery.com/before/) and [`.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) can take a jQuery object as a parameter. You just have to create your new object, store it in a variable and then pass it to `.before()` or `.append()`.

**Quick example:**

​`<div id="bin"> </div>` ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

```
var newElement;

$(document).ready(function() {

   newElement = $("<button>New button</button>");
   $("#bin").append(newElement);

   alert(newElement.text());
});​
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure exactly what you're trying to do here but if you want to save the result of a jQuery selector, you'd do it just like you would any other variable:

```
var gallery = $("#rGallery");
```

If you want to create a new element and save it:

```
var gallery = document.createElement("section");
// Do other stuff on it, like set attributes, etc.
```

Comment: Rad, didn't realize that before() could take an object instead of string!

Comment: @AaronLS yep I realized that shortly after saving my answer. Edited.

Comment: accepted @jasontowne's answer because he explained the method instead as well as giving the technical answer